# Replace a word with awk using if else statement

Tags: if-statement, awk

I am trying to replace a word in awk using an if else statement.

Below is what I have already attempted. Basically if the thrid word is "Normal", change it to 0, else change it to 1.

```
awk -F "," '{(if $3=='Normal') {$3=0}; else {$3=1} }' filename
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a proper `if - else` condition, followed with a trigger to print the line:

```
awk '{if ($3=="Normal") {$3=0} else {$3=1}}1' file
```

Here, `1` acts as a True condition, which triggers `awk`'s default behaviour, consisting in printing the current line.

You can use a ternary operator for this, though:

```
awk '{$3=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}1' file
```

Note also that you are dealing with `,`-delimited fields, so you need to preserve them afterwards. For that, use `OFS` (output field separator). All together:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}1' file
```

---

Given a sample file like this:

```
$ cat a
hello,how,are,you
i,am,Normal,buuu
```

This would return:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}1' a
hello,how,1,you
i,am,0,buuu
```

---

#### What was wrong with your approach?

```
awk -F "," '{(if $3=='Normal') {$3=0}; else {$3=1} }' filename
```

- You are using `{(if condition) {action}; else {action}}`. This has several problems:

  - the condition in `if` is the one within parentheses: `if (condition)` instead of `(if condition)`.
  - You say `(if condition) {action}` and then `;`. With this semi-colon, the `if`-statement gets finished and the next action will be executed anyways. So just drop it and say `if (condition) {...} else {...}` without this `;` before `else`.
  - You are using single quotes in `$3=='Normal'`. This is closing the awk-statement and hence not being interpreted properly, so you need to use double quotes: `$3=="Normal"`.
- Missing a `print` to have the line printed.

Comment: If i wanted $ 4 to be 0 based on $3, is this possible? I have tried adding                      {$4=($3=='Normal') ? 0 : 1}0   but it isnt changing $4

Comment: @adrianwhite note you need to use double quotes. Please show what exact command you are running, because this `0` after the last `}` is also suspicious.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}1                                    {$4=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}0'  file

Comment: @adrianwhite just drop the `0` and say `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1} {$4=($3=="Normal") ? 0 : 1}1' file`, although it may be easier to read with `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($3=="Normal") {$3=0; $4=0} else {$3=1; $4=1}}1' file`.